# Summing up values in jinja2

Tags: jinja2

What would be the right way of getting the sum of the `value` in `details.sections.details` filtered by another attribute which would be the the value in `name`, i.e.: `Earnings` / `Deduction`?

Given the data:

```json
{
   "details":{
      "totalPay":482.66,
      "currency":"OMR",
      "contributions":48.24,
      "sections":[
         {
            "name":"Earnings",
            "value":519.41,
            "details":[
               {
                  "name":"Overtime",
                  "value":60,
                  "notes":"Border OT",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"H R A",
                  "value":96,
                  "notes":"",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"LIVING ALLOWANCE",
                  "value":32,
                  "notes":"",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"T A",
                  "value":32,
                  "notes":"",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"Basic salary",
                  "value":299.408,
                  "notes":"",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Deductions",
            "value":36.75,
            "details":[
               {
                  "name":"PASI - Employee (7%) - Employee",
                  "value":32.1586,
                  "notes":null,
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"Social Security Recovery (1%) - Employee",
                  "value":4.5941,
                  "notes":null,
                  "currency":"OMR"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I would expect to get, for `Earnings`:

```
60 + 96 + 32 + 32 + 299.408 = 519.408
```

and, for the `Deductions`:

```
32.1586 + 4.5941 = 36.7527
```

I will then dispalay the summed up values in a table.

I tried

```
{% set sum =  details.sections.details|sum(attribute='value')  -%}
```

But, the script does not load and I think there is an error in it.

---

I am able to get the individual values by looping.
I have declared a variable:

```
{% set sumAdditions = 0 %}    
{% sumAdditions  = sumAdditions + details.value %}
```

but this seems to fails as the script errors out.

Comment: i am able to get the individual value by looping,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`details.sections` is a list, so you either have to filter the list for earnings and deductions:

```
{% set earnings = (
     details.sections | selectattr('name', 'eq', 'Earnings') | first
   ).details | sum(attribute='value')
%}
{% set deductions = (
     details.sections | selectattr('name', 'eq', 'Deductions') | first
   ).details | sum(attribute='value')
%}
```

---

Or do it dynamically in a loop:

```
{% set sums = {} %}
{% for section in details.sections %}
  {% do sums.update({
       section.name: section.details | sum(attribute='value') 
     }) 
  %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where `sums` will now contain a dictionary:

```py
{'Earnings': 519.408, 'Deductions': 36.7527}
```

---

If, for some reason the `{% do %}` construct is not available for you, you can use a dummy set, so assign the return of the dictionary update to a variable you won't use:

```
{% set sums = {} %}
{% for section in details.sections %}
  {% set dummy = sums.update({
       section.name: section.details | sum(attribute='value') 
     }) 
  %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: so i went with the first option. Any reason why the value of 60 in the Earnings section is missed, meaning i am getting a total of 459.408 instead of 519.408 ?

Comment: For the loop i do encounter the error,

 <p>Encountered unknown tag 'do'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.</p>

Comment: so i read that the extension needs to be enabled _jinja_env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.do'])_  and i am not entirely sure if it is in our environment

Comment: That was the nice way to do it, too bad. I edited the ugly way to do it in the answer then.

Comment: Thank you very much. The output for 'ugly' way will be exactly like the one with the _do_ loop i.e. _{'Earnings': 519.408, 'Deductions': 36.7527}_. To get the values out of the _sums_ dictionary i would have to do is _{{sums["Earnings"]_}} ?

Comment: Exactly, yes or `{{ sums.Earnings }}`.